# How to compile js files that are not web pages in gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

**EDIT**

I am trying to find a way in gatsby that

1. I can place JS files (not react components that become pages)
2. The JS files get compiled (e.g. test.ts -> asdf9a8s7d8f7as.js)
3. The JS files go under `public` which means they are accessible on a web server.

---

Let's say I have a js file that I want to link to from web pages.

```js
// src/pages/functions.js it's more complicated than this
someUsefulFunction = () => { ... }

// src/pages/index.jsx
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      my web page.
      <script src="./functions.js" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

`src/pages/functions.js` is not a react component  It is just a js files with some functions in it.
Since fuctions.js needs to be accessible on a web server, it is under `src/pages`.

When I do `gatsby develop` with the setups like above, it works fine, but when I do `gatsby build`, it show errors like this

> WebpackError: Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for   the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

It looks very stupid to use `script` tag when you can just import the file, but I am working on a project where there are conditions that I need to link my js files through `script` tag.
Am I doing it wrong? or it's not possible to compile simple js files?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other files under ***./src/pages/***
Other files can confuse gatsby( idk how but it can.)

check this [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1499#issuecomment-338805762)

Comment: Yes, this is the same case.  I know if I move js files that are not intented to be pages out of `src/pages`, then `gatsby build` works, but then those js files won't be available under `public`.  which means they don't get compiled.

Comment: if you put your js files under static folder, they will copied under the public folder and will not be proccessed by Webpack

Comment: Yes, and thanks again.   I know anything under `project/static` will be copied onto `public`, but they are just copied.  They don't get compiled.

Comment: You'll need to use the `import` syntax for the file otherwise webpack won't touch it. Since you "have" to use the script tag the `static` folder is the only thing you can do.